# Uploadify plugin in ASP MVC display HTTP 302 error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, uploadify

I have implemented Uploadify plugin on my site (site has authentication/authorization implemented). And it works fine except it display me 302 HTTP error. 
I google a little and find [this article](http://trycatchfail.com/blog/post/2009/05/13/using-flash-with-aspnet-mvc-and-authentication.aspx) but I still missing something. I suspect that error is somewhere in JS part. I saw similar questions here on stack and read them all but still have a problem :(

```
<script>    
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#file_upload').uploadify({
            'uploader': '../../Scripts/uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': '../../ImageController/UploadImage',
            'cancelImg': '../../Scripts/uploadify/cancel.png',
            'scriptData': { 'token': '@Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value' },
            'folder': '/uploads',            
            'auto': false,
            'buttonText': 'Upload image',
            'displayData': 'speed',
            'multi': 'true',
            'fileExt': '*.jpg;*.gif;*.png',
            'fileDesc': 'Image Files',
            onError: function (event, queueID, fileObj, errorObj) {
                alert("Error!!! Type: [" + errorObj.type + "] Info [" + errorObj.info + "]");
            }
        });
    });
</script>

[HttpPost]
        [TokenizedAuthorizeAttribute]
        public ActionResult UploadImage(string token, string returnUrl)
        {
            //wip
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(token);
            if (ticket != null)
            {
                var identity = new FormsIdentity(ticket);
                if (identity.IsAuthenticated)
```

Comment: Check the upload folder path is correct and also the path for 'script' parameter

Comment: FIle is uploaded fine. But after upload it display this error.

Comment: If you examine the 302 response using Fiddler or a similar tool, where is the request being redirected?  Most likely the redirect is to your login page.

Answer (score 1):

302 is redirect. I am guessing Uploadify treats anything that is not 200 as an error. Are you redirecting at the end of your UploadImage action?

Comment: Yes in the end I have 'return RedirectToAction("Index", "Gallery");'

Comment: @1110 well that's exactly your problem. You shouldn't be redirecting from the upload target action. Instead redirect from Uploadify success handler.

Comment: But onComplete is never fired. Only onError.

Comment: @1110 yes, because you have redirect in your upload action

Comment: I have made Upload action method to be void. Now when I press upload button file is uploaded. But onComplete or onError never invoked.

Comment: Ok, so make a debug effort? Fire up Fiddler and see what response returned. See if you have an error in your onComplete. See if onAllComplete is being fired.

Comment: Ok I fix it. But I don't understand anything. Upload method must not be void. I change it to return string. And after successful upload I return 'return " "' (return "" doesn't work) and it works fine, go in onComplete and redirect to another action. But can somebody explain me what was problem here? But again it is not ideal becouse when I add [Authorize attribute] it doesn't work again...

Answer (score 0):

In the end this was not redirection issue. This is authorization issue and I find solution here. With [this guide](http://zootfroot.blogspot.com/2010/12/mvc-file-upload-using-uploadify-with.html) uploadify and asp mvc work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

I also got error in Firefox.... Everythings seams work fine in IE.

So I started HttpScoop(Fiddler on PC) and viewed the result pane. I was a permanent redirect to my auhenticate view. The problem as I see it is that the swf/iframe needs to be authenticated.
I check if there's a cookie sent in form and it contains (upload) in path. Sure this can be more finetuned, but it will do for now.

Solution I did was:
I added a FormAuth key to uploadify. I then grab it in my AdminAttribute.

```
var auth = "@(Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName]==null ? string.Empty : Request.Cookies[FormsAuthentication.FormsCookieName].Value)";



$("#file_upload").uploadify({
            'formData'      : {'ListId' : '@modelData.ListId', 'folder' : '@path', 'sessionid' : '@Session.SessionID', 'token' : auth},
    ...
```

**And the AllowAdminAttribute:**

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class | AttributeTargets.Method, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = true)]
public sealed class AllowAdminAttribute : System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public AllowAdminAttribute(){
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Authorize user
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="filterContext">AuthorizationContext filterContext</param>
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool hasCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["token"] != null;

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Contains("upload") && hasCookie){
        }
        else
        {
            if (!filterContext.HttpContext.User.IsInRole("admin"))
                filterContext.Result = GetFailedResult();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Display the login view if user is a non admin and tries to access admin area.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>A login view</returns>
    private ActionResult GetFailedResult()
    {
        return new ViewResult { ViewName = "/Views/Shared/LogOn.cshtml" };
    }
}
```

I also needed to add it to my  AdminAuthorize class

```
public sealed class AdminAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool adminAuthorization = filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAdminAttribute), true) || filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(AllowAdminAttribute), true);

        //Hack for upload(Uploadify will break)
        bool hasCookie = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Params["token"] != null;

        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Path.Contains("upload") && hasCookie){
            adminAuthorization = false;
        }

        if (adminAuthorization)
        {
            base.OnAuthorization(filterContext);
        }
    }
}
```